# It appears that there were attempted hacking attempts on my Ubuntu and I did screenshots, is this genuine or false readings?

Tags: malware, ubuntu

[image: apparmor]

It appears that my computer has given false readings or under some sort of hacking attempt and I did scans and found trojan agents on my windows partition. Even after the scan I keep finding trojan agents mysteriously being found again in another scan. Can my ubuntu system be under some sort of attempted attack? I have more pictures; but due to my reputation I cannot post more than two. I have seen stack smashing attempts around the time I found the viruses via clamscan. I also looked at my logs and did a forensic scan and found suspicious activities like unknown uids and strange ports. I also looked at apparmor and it reported CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE I searched up what this means on the internet and the website told me it was to bypasss file operation (rwx) checks. This  was also happening around the time suspicious activity appears to be happening. Can this be a false reading it just doesn't seem like coincidence. 
[image: apparmor]

Comment: unfortunately, we are not technical support or a virus removal forum.

Comment: At a glance, the lower image looks like NoScript is triggering on youtube annotation functionality (?)

Comment: If your computer is connected to the internet, you don't need to worry about whether or not somebody is trying to hack into it - because you can pretty much guarantee that somebody *will* be trying to hack into it.  That's why you need a good firewall.  In general, looking at the firewall logs is a bad idea, because you will only get increasingly paranoid.  Let it do its job.  Meanwhile, NoScript fires off alarms all the time, even on perfectly legitimate sites.  Learn to live with that as well.

Comment: I guess it was a false reading. One of my scenarios I'd imagined. Not surpised thought that it is probably a false reading. Its just suspious that these false readings where happening around the time when I found trojans on my windows partition. It got me thinking while typing this, could this be a new hybrid virus both for windows and linux. Anyway, I guess its just a false reading and which is the reason why i asked the professionals online to get their expert opinion so that I can conclude that this is usually a false reading.